# Hospital department for patients with addictions?

Tags: addiction, hospital

I'm working on a Hungarian to English translation. In some Hungarian hospitals, there is a department called the "Addictions Dept." (the doctors working there are addictionologists). Those treated there are generally suffering from alcohol or drug dependence. Treatment very often starts in rehab and continues with, for example, group therapy. What would the correct term for this department in a US hospital be? Substance Use Disorder Department? I have also read about "Behavioral Health Departments", but what we're dealing with here is not strictly psychiatric care "on its own". Thank you in advance.

Comment: I checked a few large hospitals and none of them seem to have a specific name for such a department. They usually provide those services under the umbrella of the psychiatry department and they may give it various names such as "addiction services" or "behavioral health." I'm sure there are exceptions but I don't think there's a nationally recognized name in the US. Other English speaking countries may be different.

Comment: There's still a addiction medicine fellowship  in US but that's under department of medicine

Comment: My understanding in the US is that addiction care is almost entirely at facilities outside medical hospitals. Hospitals will address overdoses, severe withdrawal symptoms, etc, but rehab or group therapy are going to be at a dedicated psychiatric facility, possibly one specific to addiction or possibly one with broader mental health care. Some of these facilities may still be called 'hospitals' or might have hospital affiliation, but it's likely not the same building that has a dept of surgery, dept of oncology, etc. I'm certain you can find exceptions to that, though.

Comment: For examples on either end of the economic spectrum, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendota_Mental_Health_Institute and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazelden_Foundation

Comment: @CareyGregory, thank you for your ideas. I think I'll go for "Addiction Services" - it seeks kind of self-explanatory and doesn't beat about the bush in the same way as "Substance Use Disorder Department". I think we can consider the issue closed.

Comment: @physicsapproval, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @BryanKrause, thank you for your help and research.